# Analysis from unique values from one column naming files from another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code that I am using to loop through unique values in my data set and it works great, but I would like to change the export name to a more appropriate unique value that I can use in a dashboard.  The following is the code that I have where x in path is taken from teams unique names.  However, for this part only, I'd like the name to be assigned from a list outside of the original dataframe.

```
team = df['RSA'].unique()

for x in team:

    path2 = r'C:\Users\davidlopez\Desktop\regions\%s.csv' %x
    r = HROs['RSA'] == x
    Completed = HROs['Current Team Simple'].isin(['Completed'])
    table = HROs[Completed & r]
    top20 = table.groupby(['To Position Title']).RequestNumber.count().sort_values().nlargest(20)
    top20.to_csv(path2, index=True, header=True)
```

Couple of ways I've tried to solve this:

1)  Create a list and assign x in the path to the list instead of x.

```
mylist = ['HR_DASH_0034','HR_DASH_0035','HR_DASH_0036','HR_DASH_0037','HR_DASH_0038','HR_DASH_0039','HR_DASH_0040',
         'HR_DASH_0041','HR_DASH_0042','HR_DASH_0043','HR_DASH_0044','HR_DASH_0045','empty']

for x in team:

    path2 = r'C:\Users\davidlopez\Desktop\regions\%s.csv' %mylist
    r = HROs['RSA'] == x
    Completed = HROs['Current Team Simple'].isin(['Completed'])
    table = HROs[Completed & r]
    top20 = table.groupby(['To Position Title']).RequestNumber.count().sort_values().nlargest(20)
    top20.to_csv(path2, index=True, header=True)
```

That doesn't work because it doesn't loop and it doesn't align the new values to the original dataframe values.  Cross that off the list.

2)  I thought maybe a loop inside the loop would do the trick:

```
team = df['RSA'].unique()

mylist = ['HR_DASH_0034','HR_DASH_0035','HR_DASH_0036','HR_DASH_0037','HR_DASH_0038','HR_DASH_0039','HR_DASH_0040',
         'HR_DASH_0041','HR_DASH_0042','HR_DASH_0043','HR_DASH_0044','HR_DASH_0045','empty']

for x in team:

    for name in mylist:
        path2 = r'C:\Users\davidlopez\Desktop\regions\%s.csv' %name
    r = HROs['RSA'] == x
    Completed = HROs['Current Team Simple'].isin(['Completed'])
    table = HROs[Completed & r]
    top20 = table.groupby(['To Position Title']).RequestNumber.count().sort_values().nlargest(20)
    top20.to_csv(path2, index=True, header=True)
```

That didn't work either.  It just gave me the last value in mylist, but also it doesn't align the the unique values in team list appropriately.

3)  Next I created a dataframe with the unique values from team and the new list.

```
team = df['RSA'].unique()

mylist = ['HR_DASH_0034','HR_DASH_0035','HR_DASH_0036','HR_DASH_0037','HR_DASH_0038','HR_DASH_0039','HR_DASH_0040',
         'HR_DASH_0041','HR_DASH_0042','HR_DASH_0043','HR_DASH_0044','HR_DASH_0045','empty']

dict = {'RSA': team, 'DASH_ID': mylist}  

newdf = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

print (newdf)
                                RSA       DASH_ID
0          Intermountain Region, R4  HR_DASH_0034
1      Pacific Southwest Region, R5  HR_DASH_0035
2                Alaska Region, R10  HR_DASH_0036
3      Pacific Northwest Region, R6  HR_DASH_0037
4               Northern Region, R1  HR_DASH_0038
5                Eastern Region, R9  HR_DASH_0039
6   Albuquerque Service Center(ASC)  HR_DASH_0040
7         Rocky Mountain Region, R2  HR_DASH_0041
8       Research & Development(RES)  HR_DASH_0042
9             Washington Office(WO)  HR_DASH_0043
10          Southwestern Region, R3  HR_DASH_0044
11              Southern Region, R8  HR_DASH_0045
12            L2 Desc Not Available         empty
```

However, I still don't know how to get the DASH_ID column element names to export in my path mentioned above.

So in the end, HR_DASH_0034, name should align to Intermountain Region, R4 when the file is sent out.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your first approach, just use:

```
mylist = [...]  # your list definition
ml_iter = iter(mylist)
```

and inside the loop, replace mylist with:

```
path2 = r'C:\Users\davidlopez\Desktop\regions\%s.csv' %str(next(ml_iter))
```

More info: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/iter

Lemme know if this helps!

> UPDATE: Second Solution

```
for x, m in zip(team, mylist):

    path2 = r'C:\Users\davidlopez\Desktop\regions\%s.csv' %m
    r = HROs['RSA'] == x
    Completed = HROs['Current Team Simple'].isin(['Completed'])
    table = HROs[Completed & r]
    top20 = table.groupby(['To Position Title']).RequestNumber.count().sort_values().nlargest(20)
    top20.to_csv(path2, index=True, header=True)
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Ramsha, thank you for the attempt.  I received an error:OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\davidlopez\\Desktop\\regions\\<list_iterator object at 0x000002AB2321B288>.csv'

Comment: When I call the variable ml_iter I get this:  <list_iterator at 0x2ab2321b288>

Comment: probably a type-casting error - I updated my answer.

Comment: I apologize, in the end this did not work.  The list from ml_iter is getting assigned to any of the team list.